# qvfb compilation error - undefined reference to `png_create_write_struct'

Tags: linux, qt, embedded-linux

I am getting error while compiling qvfb for x11.

1> Now where is this png_create_write_struct is declared that i am getting error related to it `?`

2> Does qvbf compilation for x11 looks for libpng in host file system or it looks for libpng inside QT_source_code `?`

3> Please suggest How to resolve this error to compile successfully `?`

```
#/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.5/tools/qvfb$ make
e-opensource-src-4.8.5/lib -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lQtGui -lQtCore -lGL -lpthread -lXext -lX11 -lm
.obj/release-shared/qanimationwriter.o: In function `QAnimationWriter::QAnimationWriter(QString const&, char const*)':
qanimationwriter.cpp:(.text+0xbf): undefined reference to `png_create_write_struct'
qanimationwriter.cpp:(.text+0xca): undefined reference to `png_create_info_struct'
qanimationwriter.cpp:(.text+0xe0): undefined reference to `png_set_compression_level'
qanimationwriter.cpp:(.text+0xff): undefined reference to `png_set_write_fn'
.obj/release-shared/qanimationwriter.o: In function `QAnimationWriterMNG::write(png_struct_def*, unsigned char*, unsigned int)':
qanimationwriter.cpp:(.text._ZN19QAnimationWriterMNG5writeEP14png_struct_defPhj[QAnimationWriterMNG::write(png_struct_def*, unsigned char*, unsigned int)]+0xb): undefined reference to `png_get_io_ptr'
.obj/release-shared/qanimationwriter.o: In function `QAnimationWriterMNG::composeImage(QImage const&, QPoint const&)':
qanimationwriter.cpp:(.text._ZN19QAnimationWriterMNG12composeImageERK6QImageRK6QPoint[QAnimationWriterMNG::composeImage(QImage const&, QPoint const&)]+0x65): undefined reference to `png_write_chunk'
qanimationwriter.cpp:(.text._ZN19QAnimationWriterMNG12composeImageERK6QImageRK6QPoint[QAnimationWriterMNG::composeImage(QImage const&, QPoint const&)]+0x78): undefined reference to `png_set_sig_bytes'
qanimationwriter.cpp:(.text._ZN19QAnimationWriterMNG12composeImageERK6QImageRK6QPoint[QAnimationWriterMNG::composeImage(QImage const&, QPoint const&)]+0xda): undefined reference to `png_set_IHDR'
qanimationwriter.cpp:(.text._ZN19QAnimationWriterMNG12composeImageERK6QImageRK6QPoint[QAnimationWriterMNG::composeImage(QImage const&, QPoint const&)]+0xec): undefined reference to `png_write_info'
qanimationwriter.cpp:(.text._ZN19QAnimationWriterMNG12composeImageERK6QImageRK6QPoint[QAnimationWriterMNG::composeImage(QImage const&, QPoint const&)]+0x107): undefined reference to `png_set_bgr'
qanimationwriter.cpp:(.text._ZN19QAnimationWriterMNG12composeImageERK6QImageRK6QPoint[QAnimationWriterMNG::composeImage(QImage const&, QPoint const&)]+0x154): undefined reference to `png_write_image'
qanimationwriter.cpp:(.text._ZN19QAnimationWriterMNG12composeImageERK6QImageRK6QPoint[QAnimationWriterMNG::composeImage(QImage const&, QPoint const&)]+0x172): undefined reference to `png_write_end'
qanimationwriter.cpp:(.text._ZN19QAnimationWriterMNG12composeImageERK6QImageRK6QPoint[QAnimationWriterMNG::composeImage(QImage const&, QPoint const&)]+0x184): undefined reference to `png_destroy_write_struct'
qanimationwriter.cpp:(.text._ZN19QAnimationWriterMNG12composeImageERK6QImageRK6QPoint[QAnimationWriterMNG::composeImage(QImage const&, QPoint const&)]+0x1a8): undefined reference to `png_create_write_struct'
qanimationwriter.cpp:(.text._ZN19QAnimationWriterMNG12composeImageERK6QImageRK6QPoint[QAnimationWriterMNG::composeImage(QImage const&, QPoint const&)]+0x1b3): undefined reference to `png_create_info_struct'
qanimationwriter.cpp:(.text._ZN19QAnimationWriterMNG12composeImageERK6QImageRK6QPoint[QAnimationWriterMNG::composeImage(QImage const&, QPoint const&)]+0x1c9): undefined reference to `png_set_compression_level'
qanimationwriter.cpp:(.text._ZN19QAnimationWriterMNG12composeImageERK6QImageRK6QPoint[QAnimationWriterMNG::composeImage(QImage const&, QPoint const&)]+0x1e8): undefined reference to `png_set_write_fn'
qanimationwriter.cpp:(.text._ZN19QAnimationWriterMNG12composeImageERK6QImageRK6QPoint[QAnimationWriterMNG::composeImage(QImage const&, QPoint const&)]+0x21f): undefined reference to `png_set_filler'
.obj/release-shared/qanimationwriter.o: In function `QAnimationWriterMNG::~QAnimationWriterMNG()':
qanimationwriter.cpp:(.text._ZN19QAnimationWriterMNGD0Ev[_ZN19QAnimationWriterMNGD5Ev]+0x9e): undefined reference to `png_write_chunk'
qanimationwriter.cpp:(.text._ZN19QAnimationWriterMNGD0Ev[_ZN19QAnimationWriterMNGD5Ev]+0xb0): undefined reference to `png_destroy_write_struct'
qanimationwriter.cpp:(.text._ZN19QAnimationWriterMNGD0Ev[_ZN19QAnimationWriterMNGD5Ev]+0x176): undefined reference to `png_write_chunk'
.obj/release-shared/qanimationwriter.o: In function `QAnimationWriterMNG::setImage(QImage const&)':
qanimationwriter.cpp:(.text._ZN19QAnimationWriterMNG8setImageERK6QImage[QAnimationWriterMNG::setImage(QImage const&)]+0xc3): undefined reference to `png_write_chunk'
.obj/release-shared/qanimationwriter.o: In function `QAnimationWriterMNG::~QAnimationWriterMNG()':
qanimationwriter.cpp:(.text._ZN19QAnimationWriterMNGD2Ev[_ZN19QAnimationWriterMNGD5Ev]+0x9e): undefined reference to `png_write_chunk'
qanimationwriter.cpp:(.text._ZN19QAnimationWriterMNGD2Ev[_ZN19QAnimationWriterMNGD5Ev]+0xb0): undefined reference to `png_destroy_write_struct'
qanimationwriter.cpp:(.text._ZN19QAnimationWriterMNGD2Ev[_ZN19QAnimationWriterMNGD5Ev]+0x16e): undefined reference to `png_write_chunk'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [../../bin/qvfb] Error 1
```

locate command for libpng returns :--

```
#locate libpng
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0.46.0
/usr/share/doc/libpng12-0
/usr/share/doc/libpng12-0/ANNOUNCE
/usr/share/doc/libpng12-0/KNOWNBUG
/usr/share/doc/libpng12-0/README.Debian
/usr/share/doc/libpng12-0/README.gz
/usr/share/doc/libpng12-0/TODO
/usr/share/doc/libpng12-0/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libpng12-0/copyright
/usr/share/doc/libpng12-0/libpng-1.2.46.txt.gz
/usr/share/doc-base/libpng12
/var/lib/doc-base/documents/libpng12
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libpng12-0:i386.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libpng12-0:i386.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libpng12-0:i386.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libpng12-0:i386.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libpng12-0:i386.shlibs
```

Now if my library is here /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 after running nm command :---

```
$ nm -D /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0
00000000 A PNG12_0
         w _Jv_RegisterClasses
         w __cxa_finalize
         U __fprintf_chk
         w __gmon_start__
         U __longjmp_chk
         U __memcpy_chk
         U __snprintf_chk
         U __stack_chk_fail
         U _setjmp
         U abort
         U crc32
         U deflate
         U deflateEnd
         U deflateInit2_
         U deflateReset
         U fflush
         U fputc
         U fread
         U free
         U fwrite
         U gmtime
         U inflate
         U inflateEnd
         U inflateInit_
         U inflateReset
         U malloc
         U memcmp
         U memcpy
         U memset
00004700 T png_access_version_number
00018540 T png_build_grayscale_palette
000039b0 T png_check_sig
0001de60 T png_chunk_error
0001def0 T png_chunk_warning
00014160 T png_convert_from_struct_tm
000141a0 T png_convert_from_time_t
00004470 T png_convert_to_rfc1123
00003c80 T png_create_info_struct
00011120 T png_create_read_struct
00010ca0 T png_create_read_struct_2
00015840 T png_create_write_struct
000154c0 T png_create_write_struct_2
00003cf0 T png_data_freer
000043b0 T png_destroy_info_struct
000130f0 T png_destroy_read_struct
00014930 T png_destroy_write_struct
0001db30 T png_error
0001d8f0 T png_free
00003d80 T png_free_data
0001d8b0 T png_free_default
00006e80 T png_get_IHDR
000071a0 T png_get_PLTE
00007410 T png_get_asm_flagmask
00007400 T png_get_asm_flags
00006a90 T png_get_bKGD
000067f0 T png_get_bit_depth
00006ad0 T png_get_cHRM
00006bf0 T png_get_cHRM_fixed
00006a50 T png_get_channels
00006810 T png_get_color_type
000073e0 T png_get_compression_buffer_size
00006870 T png_get_compression_type
000045c0 T png_get_copyright
0001dfb0 T png_get_error_ptr
00006830 T png_get_filter_type
00006cd0 T png_get_gAMA
00006d10 T png_get_gAMA_fixed
00006e40 T png_get_hIST
00004600 T png_get_header_ver
00004620 T png_get_header_version
00006d90 T png_get_iCCP
000067d0 T png_get_image_height
000067b0 T png_get_image_width
000076e0 T png_get_int_32
00006850 T png_get_interlace_type
00004430 T png_get_io_ptr
000045e0 T png_get_libpng_ver
0001da30 T png_get_mem_ptr
00007430 T png_get_mmx_bitdepth_threshold
00007420 T png_get_mmx_flagmask
00007440 T png_get_mmx_rowbytes_threshold
00006fa0 T png_get_oFFs
00007010 T png_get_pCAL
00007130 T png_get_pHYs
00006930 T png_get_pixel_aspect_ratio
000068f0 T png_get_pixels_per_meter
000204b0 T png_get_progressive_ptr
000073a0 T png_get_rgb_to_gray_status
00006770 T png_get_rowbytes
00006790 T png_get_rows
000071f0 T png_get_sBIT
000070e0 T png_get_sCAL
00006e10 T png_get_sPLT
00006d50 T png_get_sRGB
00006a70 T png_get_signature
000072a0 T png_get_tIME
000072e0 T png_get_tRNS
00007230 T png_get_text
00007710 T png_get_uint_16
00007630 T png_get_uint_31
000076b0 T png_get_uint_32
00007370 T png_get_unknown_chunks
000073c0 T png_get_user_chunk_ptr
00007470 T png_get_user_height_max
0000c720 T png_get_user_transform_ptr
00007450 T png_get_user_width_max
00006750 T png_get_valid
00006990 T png_get_x_offset_microns
000069f0 T png_get_x_offset_pixels
00006890 T png_get_x_pixels_per_meter
000069c0 T png_get_y_offset_microns
00006a20 T png_get_y_offset_pixels
000068c0 T png_get_y_pixels_per_meter
00004640 T png_handle_as_unknown
00003c50 T png_info_init
00003b70 T png_info_init_3
00004450 T png_init_io
00020a90 R png_libpng_ver
0001d7b0 T png_malloc
0001d770 T png_malloc_default
0001d940 T png_malloc_warn
0001d9a0 T png_memcpy_check
0001d9d0 T png_memset_check
00004710 T png_mmx_support
000209e0 R png_pass_dsp_mask
00020a50 R png_pass_inc
000209fc R png_pass_mask
00020a6c R png_pass_start
00020a18 R png_pass_yinc
00020a34 R png_pass_ystart
00006400 T png_permit_empty_plte
00006430 T png_permit_mng_features
00020370 T png_process_data
00020400 T png_progressive_combine_row
00012cd0 T png_read_destroy
000126a0 T png_read_end
00012600 T png_read_image
00011690 T png_read_info
00013250 T png_read_png
00011ea0 T png_read_row
00012510 T png_read_rows
00011e00 T png_read_update_info
000046c0 T png_reset_zstream
0000cb70 T png_save_int_32
0000cba0 T png_save_uint_16
0000cb40 T png_save_uint_32
00005320 T png_set_IHDR
00005750 T png_set_PLTE
0000c110 T png_set_add_alpha
00006700 T png_set_asm_flags
00004d60 T png_set_bKGD
00015d70 T png_set_background
0000bfb0 T png_set_bgr
00004da0 T png_set_cHRM
00004f20 T png_set_cHRM_fixed
00006660 T png_set_compression_buffer_size
00015890 T png_set_compression_level
000158b0 T png_set_compression_mem_level
00015990 T png_set_compression_method
000158d0 T png_set_compression_strategy
000158f0 T png_set_compression_window_bits
00015c20 T png_set_crc_action
00015e70 T png_set_dither
0001df80 T png_set_error_fn
00016a40 T png_set_expand
00016a80 T png_set_expand_gray_1_2_4_to_8
0000c0a0 T png_set_filler
00014a60 T png_set_filter
00014d00 T png_set_filter_heuristics
00014580 T png_set_flush
000050a0 T png_set_gAMA
00005180 T png_set_gAMA_fixed
000169c0 T png_set_gamma
00016aa0 T png_set_gray_1_2_4_to_8
00016ae0 T png_set_gray_to_rgb
00005240 T png_set_hIST
000059c0 T png_set_iCCP
0000c070 T png_set_interlace_handling
000066e0 T png_set_invalid
0000c180 T png_set_invert_alpha
0000c1a0 T png_set_invert_mono
00006450 T png_set_keep_unknown_chunks
0001da00 T png_set_mem_fn
00006720 T png_set_mmx_thresholds
00005470 T png_set_oFFs
000054a0 T png_set_pCAL
00005720 T png_set_pHYs
0000bff0 T png_set_packing
0000c020 T png_set_packswap
00016a60 T png_set_palette_to_rgb
00020450 T png_set_progressive_read_fn
00013620 T png_set_read_fn
00013230 T png_set_read_status_fn
000065c0 T png_set_read_user_chunk_fn
00016d80 T png_set_read_user_transform_fn
00016c70 T png_set_rgb_to_gray
00016b00 T png_set_rgb_to_gray_fixed
000065e0 T png_set_rows
00005830 T png_set_sBIT
000056c0 T png_set_sCAL
00005fb0 T png_set_sPLT
00005860 T png_set_sRGB
00005880 T png_set_sRGB_gAMA_and_cHRM
0000c040 T png_set_shift
00003880 T png_set_sig_bytes
00015e30 T png_set_strip_16
00015e50 T png_set_strip_alpha
0001dfd0 T png_set_strip_error_numbers
0000bfd0 T png_set_swap
0000c160 T png_set_swap_alpha
00005df0 T png_set_tIME
00005e30 T png_set_tRNS
00016ac0 T png_set_tRNS_to_alpha
00005d90 T png_set_text
000063c0 T png_set_unknown_chunk_location
000061e0 T png_set_unknown_chunks
00006730 T png_set_user_limits
0000c6f0 T png_set_user_transform_info
000137c0 T png_set_write_fn
000159f0 T png_set_write_status_fn
00015a10 T png_set_write_user_transform_fn
000038f0 T png_sig_cmp
00011e70 T png_start_read_image
0001dcf0 T png_warning
0000cee0 T png_write_chunk
0000cd10 T png_write_chunk_data
0000ce60 T png_write_chunk_end
0000cc60 T png_write_chunk_start
000146d0 T png_write_destroy
00013f60 T png_write_end
000145a0 T png_write_flush
000144b0 T png_write_image
00013b20 T png_write_info
00013860 T png_write_info_before_PLTE
00015a30 T png_write_png
000141d0 T png_write_row
00014530 T png_write_rows
         U pow
         U stderr
         U strlen
         U strtod
```

I searched for png.h file :---

```
# locate png.h
/home/dinesh/qt_source/qt_source_x11/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.5/src/3rdparty/libpng/png.h
/usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/png.h
```

Now lib png source is inside QT_source also :---

```
/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.5/src/3rdparty/libpng$ ls
ANNOUNCE           pngconf.h   pnglibconf.h  pngrtran.c   pngwrite.c
CHANGES            pngdebug.h  pngmem.c      pngrutil.c   pngwtran.c
INSTALL            pngerror.c  pngpread.c    pngset.c     pngwutil.c
libpng-manual.txt  pngget.c    pngpriv.h     pngstruct.h  README
LICENSE            png.h       pngread.c     pngtrans.c
png.c              pnginfo.h   pngrio.c      pngwio.c
```

====================================  EDIT  ==========================

I performed these steps, both failed :---

1> I followed following link http://www.brunolinux.com/02-The_Terminal/ldconfig.html and
   added following line to `ld.so.conf` file /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ . Then i run the `ldconfig` command.

I directly copied the command line result of make & added -lpng to it & run it

```
qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.5/tools/qvfb$ g++ -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/dinesh/qt_source/qt_source_x11/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.5/lib -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-rpath,/opt/Qt5.1.1/4.8.5_X11/gcc/lib -Wl,-rpath,/opt/Qt5.1.1/4.8.5_X11/gcc/lib -o ../../bin/qvfb .obj/release-shared/qvfb.o .obj/release-shared/qvfbview.o .obj/release-shared/qvfbratedlg.o .obj/release-shared/main.o .obj/release-shared/qanimationwriter.o .obj/release-shared/qvfbprotocol.o .obj/release-shared/qvfbshmem.o .obj/release-shared/qvfbmmap.o .obj/release-shared/qlock.o .obj/release-shared/qwslock.o .obj/release-shared/qwssignalhandler.o .obj/release-shared/deviceskin.o .obj/release-shared/qvfbx11view.o .obj/release-shared/x11keyfaker.o .obj/release-shared/moc_qvfb.o .obj/release-shared/moc_qvfbview.o .obj/release-shared/moc_qvfbratedlg.o .obj/release-shared/moc_gammaview.o .obj/release-shared/moc_qvfbprotocol.o .obj/release-shared/moc_qvfbshmem.o .obj/release-shared/moc_qvfbmmap.o .obj/release-shared/moc_deviceskin.o .obj/release-shared/moc_qvfbx11view.o .obj/release-shared/moc_x11keyfaker.o .obj/release-shared/qrc_ClamshellPhone.o .obj/release-shared/qrc_SmartPhone2.o .obj/release-shared/qrc_SmartPhone.o .obj/release-shared/qrc_SmartPhoneWithButtons.o .obj/release-shared/qrc_TouchscreenPhone.o .obj/release-shared/qrc_PortableMedia.o .obj/release-shared/qrc_S60-QVGA-Candybar.o .obj/release-shared/qrc_S60-nHD-Touchscreen.o .obj/release-shared/qrc_qvfb.o   -lpng  -L/home/dinesh/qt_source/qt_source_x11/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.5/lib -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lXtst -lQtOpenGL -L/home/dinesh/qt_source/qt_source_x11/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.5/lib -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lQtGui -lQtCore -lGL -lpthread -lXext -lX11 -lm
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpng
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [../../bin/qvfb] Error 1
```

2>  Above step did not worked so i performed below step.
I modified the qvfb.pro file of QT & added the option at the end LIBS += -lpng

```
qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.5/tools/qvfb$ sudo make
/home/dinesh/qt_source/qt_source_x11/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.5/bin/qmake -spec ../../mkspecs/linux-g++ -o Makefile qvfb.pro
g++ -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/dinesh/qt_source/qt_source_x11/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.5/lib -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-rpath,/opt/Qt5.1.1/4.8.5_X11/gcc/lib -Wl,-rpath,/opt/Qt5.1.1/4.8.5_X11/gcc/lib -o ../../bin/qvfb .obj/release-shared/qvfb.o .obj/release-shared/qvfbview.o .obj/release-shared/qvfbratedlg.o .obj/release-shared/main.o .obj/release-shared/qanimationwriter.o .obj/release-shared/qvfbprotocol.o .obj/release-shared/qvfbshmem.o .obj/release-shared/qvfbmmap.o .obj/release-shared/qlock.o .obj/release-shared/qwslock.o .obj/release-shared/qwssignalhandler.o .obj/release-shared/deviceskin.o .obj/release-shared/qvfbx11view.o .obj/release-shared/x11keyfaker.o .obj/release-shared/moc_qvfb.o .obj/release-shared/moc_qvfbview.o .obj/release-shared/moc_qvfbratedlg.o .obj/release-shared/moc_gammaview.o .obj/release-shared/moc_qvfbprotocol.o .obj/release-shared/moc_qvfbshmem.o .obj/release-shared/moc_qvfbmmap.o .obj/release-shared/moc_deviceskin.o .obj/release-shared/moc_qvfbx11view.o .obj/release-shared/moc_x11keyfaker.o .obj/release-shared/qrc_ClamshellPhone.o .obj/release-shared/qrc_SmartPhone2.o .obj/release-shared/qrc_SmartPhone.o .obj/release-shared/qrc_SmartPhoneWithButtons.o .obj/release-shared/qrc_TouchscreenPhone.o .obj/release-shared/qrc_PortableMedia.o .obj/release-shared/qrc_S60-QVGA-Candybar.o .obj/release-shared/qrc_S60-nHD-Touchscreen.o .obj/release-shared/qrc_qvfb.o    -L/home/dinesh/qt_source/qt_source_x11/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.5/lib -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lXtst -lpng -lQtOpenGL -L/home/dinesh/qt_source/qt_source_x11/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.5/lib -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lQtGui -lQtCore -lGL -lpthread -lXext -lX11 -lm
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpng
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [../../bin/qvfb] Error 1
```

============================= EDIT =================

Thanks everyone its working.

creating softlink works :--
ln -s /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpng.so

this worked :---
-L/lib/i386-linux-gnu -lpng

Also you can directly modify your qvfb.pro file, instead of putting in directly in command line  :---
LIBS = -L/lib/i386-linux-gnu -lpng

Comment: please suggest on this question any help will be appreciable.!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem. If you look at the compilation line to link qvfb that causes the error, you'll see that it just misses -lpng to indicate to link with libpng. It's just a workaround, but once you've run 'make' once, you can simply copy and past the faulty compilation line and add -lpng at the end. It worked for me.

Comment: I did as per your suggestion it failed for me. getting error that -lpng not found. I have edited the post above please suggest.

Comment: Thanks everyone its working. 

creating softlink works :-- 
ln -s /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpng.so 

this worked :--- 
-L/lib/i386-linux-gnu -lpng